# Why does my jQuery dialog resize and content disappear?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, dialog, center, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have an MVC3 view which calls a partial view which gets a model containing some settings, you can find the code below.

I don't understand why every time my window is resized, my whole dialog box resizes and the initial content disappears.

I tried various "centering" functions but they all yield the same output. I'm using IE9.

```
<div id="dialog">  
    <p>@Model.Message</p>  
</div>  

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            title: "@Model.Title",
            show: "blind",
            width: "@Model.Width",
            height: "@Model.Height",
            buttons: {"Ok": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); }
            },
            close: function(event, ui) {
                @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ReturnUrl))
                {
                    @:location.href = "@Url.Action("" + @Model.Action + "", "" + @Model.Controller + "", new { returnUrl = "" + @Model.ReturnUrl + "" })"
                }
                else { 
                    @:close: function(event, ui) { $(this).close(); }
                }
            },
            modal: true,
            resizable: false     
        });
    });  

 jQuery.fn.center = function () {
        this.css("position","absolute");
        this.css("top", ( $(window).height() - this.height() ) / 2+$(window).scrollTop() + "px");
        this.css("left", ( $(window).width() - this.width() ) / 2+$(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
        return this;
    }

$(window).resize(function(){
    $("#dialog").center();
 });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't recognizing that the dialog element you use as selector is not the parent of the dialog widget. The element gets wrapped so that your selector element becomes the content area.

Outer wrapper has class="ui-dialog". In your plugin function target `$(this).closest('.ui-dialog')` to make your posiiton adjustments. It is already set to `position:absolute` during creation.

Comment: thank you, i was able to fix my issue by using the code snippet below.

Comment: $(window).resize(function(){
        $('.ui-dialog').center();
     });